# Adhibeturne tempus perfectum/imperfectum aut presens cum de homine mortuo loqueris?

Tags: perfect-tense, tenses, imperfectum

In English, when a person who is deceased is being discussed, specifically when ascribing an attribute, concept, thing, etc. to them with a copulative verb, the simple past is typically used. E.g:

> Julius Caesar *was* a conqueror.
>
> LLPSI *was* written by Hans Ørberg

Whereas when discussing a person who is still living, the simple present is typically used (unless the attribute, concept, thing, etc. being ascribed is something that the subject no longer is).

Does Latin make this same distinction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a native English speaker, I would use a past tense to describe something that was once true but no longer is, and the present to describe something that is still true. Barack Obama *was* the president; Donald Trump *is* the president (as of the time of writing). Similarly, Julius Caesar *was* a conqueror, because he hasn't conquered anything for a few thousand years now.

I would do the same in Latin: *Obama **erat** praesidens*, but *Trump **est** praesidens*. The choice of perfect versus imperfect depends on whether I'm describing a state or an event; since being president lasts for a significant period of time, the imperfect feels more natural. On the other hand, *Caesar **perivit***, not *perebat*, since I consider it a single event rather than a state of being.

The second example is a bit misleading: the full verb in English is "was written", since most passives in English are formed with a form of "be" with the passive participle. Latin sometimes does the same, but uses the tenses a bit differently: the direct equivalent would be *scriptus **est***, with a present-tense form of *esse*. But the compound verb is still in the perfect tense, since the writing is over and done with now.

Comment: Gratulor, quod iam decem milia punctorum tulisti!

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Gratias! :D